# does abraham's twitteroauth library work for update_with_media?

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

does abraham's twitteroauth library work for update_with_media?

I'm using below code but it returns me         stdClass Object
(
    [request] => /1/statuses/update_with_media.json
    [error] => Error creating status.
)

```
session_start();
require_once('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
require_once('config.php');


if (empty($_SESSION['access_token']) || empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token']) || empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token_secret'])) {
  header('Location: ./clearsessions.php');
}

 $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET,$_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token_secret']);

$image = './images/5298.png';
$content = $connection->post('statuses/update_with_media', 
  array(
   'media[]' => '@{$image};type=image/jpeg;filename={$image}', 
   'status' => 'My current location'));

include('html.inc');
```

Any one any idea how to solve this problem?

**EDIT 1:** I am using https://upload.twitter.com/1/ as url

Comment: As far as I am aware, you don't need the ;type=image/jpeg;filename={$image}
Does it work if you try it without them?

Comment: No....it doesn't work without it

Comment: For the new Twitter Media Upload check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26340704/twitter-image-upload-error-media-parameter-is-missing/26931378#26931378

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it does! Change the two files Oauth.php and twitteroauth.php as the described at this link https://github.com/robhaswell/twitteroauth/commit/7f5bfd2450cb1cff71641d7ea55e118f5a42885d and use $connection->upload method like this.

```
 $params = array('media[]' => '@'.$image_url, 'status' => $messafe);
 $twit = $connection->upload('statuses/update_with_media',$params);
```

Comment: Since api 1.1, you have to change proposed "upload" method in twitterOAuth.php. Juste delete the 2 definitions of $this->host (line 168 and 170 on github diff). Worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As per library author answer elsewhere - No it does not work with update_with_media yet.

> TwitterOAuth does not currently support media uploads. I hope to add
>   support in the future.
>   on 10th of May by @abraham at [update_with_media using abraham's twitteroauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530385/update-with-media-using-abrahams-twitteroauth)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $params = array('media[]' => file_get_contents($image_url), 'status' => $messafe);
 $twit = $connection->upload('statuses/update_with_media',$params);
```

A little change if update_with_media is not working